# Import TAB delimited csv in python and strip /n and , from description field

Tags: python, export, import, csv

I have been trying to do this in python for a couple days now and I have it working sort of but I am stuck on this last error:

File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames:

here is what I have for code:

```
import csv
import sys

fin = 'csvTest.txt'
fout = open('test2.csv','wb')
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(fin, 'r'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')

fieldnames = ['fName', 'lName', 'addr1', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'terms', 'apptDate', 'product', 'description', 'quantity', 'price', 'total', 'taxAmt', 'invoiceNum']
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(fout, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=fieldnames)
csvwriter.writeheader()
for row in csv_file:
    row = row['fName'], row['lName'], row['addr1'], row['city'], row['state'], row['zip'], row['terms'], row['apptDate'], row['product'],     
row['description'].replace('/n','').replace(',',''), row['quantity'], row['price'], row['total'], row['taxAmt'], row['invoiceNum']
print(row)
csvwriter.writerow(row)
fout.close()
```

I am simply trying to import a csv file and strip off all /n and , from the description field ONLY then write them back out as a TAB delimited CSV.  I have tried a few ways of making this work but am having trouble targeting the right field.  This is my first go at csv with python.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your long row assignment line converts the dictionary row object into a tuple object. The error you're seeing is the csv library complaining that you didn't pass it a dict object. Also, the indentation is a little screwy (but that could just be StackOverflow).

```
import csv
import sys

with open('csvTest.txt', 'rb') as file_in:
    with open('test2.csv','wb') as file_out:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_in, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')

        fieldnames = ['fName', 'lName', 'addr1', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'terms', 
                      'apptDate', 'product', 'description', 'quantity', 'price', 
                      'total', 'taxAmt', 'invoiceNum']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for row in csv_reader:
            row['description'] = row['description'].replace('/n','').replace(',','')
            print(row)
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This worked GREAT!  I am just getting started here I did have to take the b flag from the import and export files or I got an error about opening it in text mode.  I had trouble pasting it into the question box so I am sure that's what happened to the spacing.

Thank you again this helped me see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: One may need to replace multiple chars: `.replace('/n','').replace(',','')..replace('\t','')`. In my case, `\t` was the culprit. For others, even `\r` may be relevant.